# installation of ubuntu 12.04 64bit on msi gt70 2OC

Tags: 12.04, installation, boot, live-usb, msi

ok so my problem is i can't install the 64 bit version of ubuntu on my system, i have tried every bios config shown in threads but it stops on the screen after selecting install ubuntu. I'm installing via usb i have tried using legacy mode and uefi both with fast boot on and off. the strangest thing is i can install the 32bit version via legacy mode no problems

system specs are as follows,
core I7-4700MQ
Nvidia GT770m 3gig
32gig ram
128gig SSD as OS drive
750gig HDD as back-up drive

let me know if you need any more details, i have not been able to find any threads that are even close to my problem

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should install your Ubuntu x64 with the advance option (<kbd>F6</kbd>) `nomodeset`.

I'm not sure if this problem is common in MSI models, but I read some info related to the newer MSI GE70 [here](https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/issues/516).